# VB.Net - Removing image.PropertyItems data

Tags: vb.net, image, metadata

How do I successfully remove an images property items? I have tried loading the image and then looping thru using the image.ProperyIdList and then calling .RemovePropertyItem and then saving the image to a new file, but the new file still has all the metadata.  I have also tried to zero out all the bytes for each propertyItem.value but that causes a genric gdi+ error when I save.  I have also tried pushing the image into a memeory stream and back, thinking it would clear the metadata.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish the following by using the code below.  It is not the fastest but it does work.  I basically strip off the metadata I want and then create a new image for the web with no properties, thus making sure the personal data is off the photo.

```
Using img As Image = Image.FromFile(fileName)
            Using newImage As New Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height)

                Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
                    gr.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Bilinear
                    gr.DrawImage(img, New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height))
                End Using
                newImage.Save(newFileName)
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: Hmm, just did this, but noted the file size increased by about 14k, just for those who come after... (30.694 bytes up to 45,191 bytes after saving)