# .NET Image.RemovePropertyItem has no obvious effect

Tags: .net, image

I've been working on removing Exif metadata from images before feeding them into some ML algorithms.

My example image is [this one](http://www.aedsuperstore.com/assets/images/PAD-BAG-02-T-Thumb.jpg), a small 100x100 image that contains more than 500kB of metadata, downloaded that as `backpack.jpg`. File size on disk is 584kB.

First thing: just load the image, save it back to disk:

```ml
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Drawing.Imaging
// Image from http://www.aedsuperstore.com/assets/images/PAD-BAG-02-T-Thumb.jpg
// downloaded as c:/temp/backpack.jpg, File size 584kB
let img = Bitmap.FromFile "c:/temp/backpack.jpg"
// Saves into a file of 563kB
img.Save "c:/temp/backpack_unchanged.jpg"
```

It was strange to see that the file size went down by 20kB, to 563kB, but I ignored that initially (I blamed default encoder quality)

The image has one item of metadata that occupies more than 500000 bytes:

```ml
> img.GetPropertyItem 34675;;
val it : PropertyItem =
  System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem
    {Id = 34675;
     Len = 557168;
     Type = 1s;
...
```

To remove metadata, I went through all property items, and called `RemovePropertyItem`:

```ml
let ids = img.PropertyIdList
for id in ids do
    img.RemovePropertyItem id
if img.PropertyIdList.Length <> 0 then
    failwith "There are properties left?"
```

No exception thrown, all properties seem to have been removed.

Then save to disk - and I get back a file of 584kB:

```ml
// Saves into a file of 584 kB
img.Save("c:/temp/backpack_removed.jpg")
```

The two big questions now:

- Why did removing the property items not have any obvious effect? Can I do anything to make it have an effect?
- Why does the image size on disk go back up to the original 584kB when saved for a second time?

There are two related questions on MSDN, [one with an answer that I found not helpful](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18af2876-efa2-442f-b1b6-9583cbe47a71/removepropertyitem?forum=csharpgeneral) and [one without an answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/042b0cee-3258-484c-a819-d446a5ae993d/problems-with-imageremovepropertyitem?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues). The [.NET documentation for `RemovePropertyItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.removepropertyitem(v=vs.110).aspx) does not say anything specific either. There's a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117008/vb-net-removing-image-propertyitems-data) that offers a workaround, but no explanation.

Fwiw, what works reliably to remove metadata is to re-draw the image, like this:

```ml
// Saves into a file of 19kB
let reDrawn = new Bitmap(img)
reDrawn.Save("c:/temp/backpack_reDrawn.jpg")
```

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this issue.
It seems that if you try to remove all items in PropertyItems, they will be removed once in memory, but when you save the image to disk, all property items will come back.
I don't know why, but as a workaround, when you remove items, you can leave one of them untouched.
If you are not happy with its value, you can simply set its value to a blank byte[].

```
        foreach (var prop in bm.PropertyItems)
        {

            if (prop.Id == 0x10F)//PropertyTagEquipMake
            {//I picked 0x10F because I assume it exists in most images.
                PropertyItem pi = bm.GetPropertyItem(prop.Id);
                pi.Value = new byte[] { 0 };
                bm.SetPropertyItem(pi);
            }
            else
            {
                bm.RemovePropertyItem(prop.Id);
            }

        }
```

But finally I chose to use the solution same as yours, it looks more reliable and clean. I was curious about RemovePropertyItem() then dug a little deeper.
Just FYI.